# Vb.net wild cards in registry path

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry, wildcard, registrykey

I want to read a registry value which resides in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProgram\PROG7.0.0\Info
```

The value name is "***Information***" but the key "***PROG7.0.0***" may have a variable name like "***PROG7.2.111***", changing the path to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProgram\PROG7.2.111\Info
```

The variable name will always be of the form "***PROG7.xx.xxx***", where **x** is an integer. Also, there will always be exactly one subkey of such name in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProgram`

I know i can use `Regestry.GetValue` method for reading a registry value but in my case the path is a variable - how can i go about it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to iterate all keys at a specific registry path

```
using System;

using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RegistryLister {
    public static class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MyProgram\");
            var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\");
            if (key != null)
                foreach (var keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames()) {
                    //if (keyName.StartsWith("PROG7"))
                    if (keyName.StartsWith("Mic"))
                        Console.WriteLine(keyName);
                }
            Console.ReadKey();

            /* Outputs:
             * 
             * Microsoft
             * Microsoft Corporation
             * 
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx)